# ng-class with multiple conditions

Tags: angularjs, if-statement, conditional-statements, ng-class

I want to show the class based on the value present in it.

```
ng-if="data.percentage >= 0  & data.percentage < 25"
ng-if="data.percentage >= 25 & data.percentage < 50"
ng-if="data.percentage >= 50 & data.percentage < 75"
ng-if="data.percentage >= 75 & data.percentage <= 100"

.firstLabel
.secondLabel
.thirdLabel
.fourthLabel
```

For example, if the value in `data.percentage` is 75 then my output div should look like this.

```
<div ng-class="fourthLabel" > </div>
```

help is appriciated thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to combine them all in a single [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClasshttps://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) like so.

This will apply the class corresponding to the condition which is true.

```
<div ng-class="{'firstLabel': data.percentage >= 0  & data.percentage < 25, 'secondLabel':data.percentage >= 25 & data.percentage < 50, 'thirdLabel': data.percentage >= 50 & data.percentage < 75, 'fourthLabel':data.percentage >= 75 & data.percentage <= 100 }" > </div>
```